# mysql returns correct result field length but content is truncated

Tags: mysql, delphi, odbc, ado

I'm using delphi/ado/odbc to connect to mysql server. After executing the following statement:

```
SHOW CREATE VIEW aViewName
```

The "Create View" field in the result set contains a very long string (> 4096 chars). Although the length of the content is correct, I got 4096 bytes right with some garbage characters append to it.

Is this a bug in mysql odbc driver or is the limitation of ADO?

Comment: Does this apply to all results? Would a field of type `VARCHAR(5000)` filled with `x` be truncated at the same point?

Comment: If you are looking at the contents of the field in the debugger be aware that it shows garbage if field is too long.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Instead of using "SHOW CREAT VIEW ...", I use information_schema to retrieve the view creation sql by executing following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.VIEWS where TABLE_NAME="aViewName"
```

It looks like if the select result has no corresponding table structure (e.g "SHOW CREATE ..." or "SELECT 'something more than 4096 chars'") then ADO or ODBC driver will assume string content using varchar(4096).

Thanks for your comments.